# machine instruction counting for single UDP packet processing

Tags: c, linux, networking, linux-kernel, udp

is there any way to count the no of machine cycles or machine instructions used for a particular application or program?

I am trying to figure out that how many machine instructions are used for a single UDP packet processing in linux as the packet enters to NIC till it is given to the application which is trying to get it. by getting this info we can find that how much kernel overhead is added for packet processing.

Comment: Probably not. The NIC will have at least a small buffer of its own to store some data before it copies it into the main memory of the machine. The CPU doesn't know the data exists at all until that happens.

Comment: @Jessy Coffin lets assume NIC has put the data in the main memory....actualy i want to know how much kernel code executed(so no of machine instructions) which adds overhead as TCP/IP processing part,interrupt handling, socket invocation.

Comment: What are the constraints? Are you willing to modify the NIC driver? This is surely doable. Are you willing to include the cycles consumed by recv()?

Comment: @Gille actually i want to modify the TCP/IP networking stack for UDP processing so that we can get UDP packets very fast & i think it will also increase the no of packets processed per second because the application which is trying to get these packets only wants UDP. 
so there will also be a need of driver modification.

Comment: Most of UDP happens inside the kernel, and you may have hard time to measure that....

Comment: Well actually one can measure code performance to a pretty good extent: the 'perf' project seems to be one good approach.
https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page